How to perform t-student test to validate whether the final cumulative wealth of a trading algorithm is achieved by luck?
As suggested by Huang et al. (2018), in order to test whether simple luck can generate the return of a trading algorithm, it is possible to conduct a statistical test to measure the probability of this situation.

First, we separate the portfolio daily returns into two components: one benchmark-related and the other non-benchmark-related by regressing the portfolio excess returns against the benchmark excess returns. Formally, ${s_t} - {s_t}\left( F \right) = \alpha  + \beta \left( {{s_t}\left( B \right) - {s_t}\left( F \right) + \epsilon\left( t \right)} \right)$ where ${s_t}$ stands for the portfolio daily returns, ${s_t}\left( B \right)$ denotes the daily returns of the benchmark (market index) and ${s_t}\left( F \right)$ is the daily returns of the risk-free assets (here, we simply choose Treasury bill and set it to 1.000156, or equivalently, annual interest of 4%). This regression estimates the portfolio’s alpha($\alpha$), which indicates the performance of the investment after accounting for the involved risk. Then, we conduct a statistical t-test to evaluate whether alpha is significantly different from zero, by using the t statistic $\frac{\alpha }{{SE\left( \alpha  \right)}}$, where $SE\left( \alpha  \right)$ is the standard error for the estimated alpha. Thus, by assuming the $\alpha$ is normally distributed, we can obtain the probability that the returns of the proposed strategy are generated by simple luck. Generally speaking, the smaller the probability, the higher confidence the trading strategy.

However, it is not specified what is the value of $\epsilon\left( t \right)$ or how they determine the value of $\beta$ in the equation above. Any suggestions?

Most likely the equation should be:
${s_t} - {s_t}\left( F \right) = \alpha  + \beta ( {{s_t}( B ) - {s_t}( F ) ) + \epsilon ( t )} $
So $\epsilon ( t )$ are just the residuals of the regression. On average they will be zero. They will have positive standard deviation though.
This is just a simple CAPM type regression, with some weird notation.

Sounds like Huang et al. have re-invented Jensen's Alpha.

It's crazy the lengths people go to re-invest the wheel, call it something else and don't attribute proper citations. That's why I avoid predatory journals ...
